# Url Rewriting - Always redirecting to index.php

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

i'm trying to rewrite some simple urls:

```
http://www.site.com/folder/index.php?page=something
```

into

```
http://www.site.com/folder/something
```

here's my .htaccess file ( placed in /folder/ )

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [R]
```

with this rule i always get this URL

```
    http://www.site.com/folder/index.php?page=index.php
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change

```
 
RewriteBase /folder
```

to

```
RewriteBase /folder/
```

Second, change

```
 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [R]
```

to

```
 
  RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

That should work. The **QSA** part is to allow any querystring in the address to be carried over to the new address; otherwise, they will be dropped.

### Edit

In that case, try this

```
 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

similar to what you had earlier. 
Unless you have other patterns, that should achieve what you need 
 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Ehm... this is not working.
It correctly works for `http://www.site.com/folder` and `http://www.site.com/folder/index.php` but i get error when i write:

`http://www.site.com/folder/something`

Comment: Thanks to your tip and Michel Feldheim too i succeeded.
Posting an answer for the complete solution editing the question.

Comment: That's good; kindly accept one of the answers as the answer; and upvote them too if you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

<s>You are referencing the wrong match, use `$2` like so</s>

<s>`RewriteEngine On`</s>

<s>`RewriteBase /folder`</s>

<s>`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$2 [R]`</s>

The above is infact incorrect. It seems that the `.` is not matching the correct characters (I don't know why).

The best way I can see getting round this without knowing the cause of the issue is to simply match letters and numbers like so:

```
# Turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# Set the rewrites for /folder
RewriteBase /folder

# Set the rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Mmmh, edited but now i'm getting:

    http://www.site.com/folder/index.php?page=

whatever i'm writing

    http://www.site.com/folder/something

Comment: @TiD91 Sorry, have re-read my code, you are right, this will not work. Will post up an edit in a min once I have correct :-)

Comment: @TiD91 I have looked into the issue further and I can see where you are having trouble, as I am struggling to achieve the same. Is there any reason why you have to use the `RewriteBase` rule, or would you be happy with another solution?

Comment: I need the RewriteBase rule because if i do not set it i get the full address with the webserver (not public) folders. :D

Answer (score 0):

Your initial rule worked perfectly. The only problem was the [R] modifier which **redirected** /folder/something to /folder/index.php?page=something and caused a second request.

Apply your rule on  /folder/index.php?page=something and you get /folder/index.php?page=index.php

To fix this replace [R] ( HTTP 302 Redirect ) by [L] ( leave matching chain when you match here ) and you're done

Comment: Right. Now it's working good except for main page.

If i write
`http://www.site.com/folder/`
or
`http://www.site.com/folder/index.php`

it correctly tries to rewrite without success. So how can i avoid rewriting for **index.php**?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone i succeeded in doing what i was thinking to do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/

#Excluding direct url to php files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)\.php$
#Excluding the empty space url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(\s*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png|css|js|)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score -1):

If I may suggest, please look into a generator for htaccess, such as: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

which gives you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/]*)$ /folder/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

I've editted the above, this is a working example on a local testdomain.
Perhaps this is just what you have been looking for.

Also, if I may, omitting the extension of a page is not recommendable. Google likes it to be recognizable e.g. .html or .php.

And, you should add a rewriterule for **every** parameter you add.

Finally, I would omit the index.php. Your server will automatically load index.php if no other page is found, but it doesn't have to be visible in the addressbar.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. There's a problem however, i think this is good putting the .htaccess file in the root of the webserver. 
I'd like to put it into /folder/

:D

Comment: On a generator, you can specify the prefix. The point being, using some tool to do it for you might work better than staring at this all night ;)